# VB.NET Why web browser control not display in Instagram.com

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I use VB.NET Web Browser Control Navigate to instagram.com but it's not display Why?

Here is the code I use :

```
Webbrowser1.Navigate("Instagram.com")
```

Here is a [screenshot of the result](http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=7o71k8p0I)

Comment: How do you set the url from the web browser?

Comment: perhaps help us help you with more info, errors, screenshots etc. First guess is that instagram does not like your user agent (the browser) or some javascript doesn't run which was required.

Comment: @Andy I use code Webbrowser1.Navigate("Instagram.com")

Comment: @ericosg I'm already enable Script and this screenshot http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=7o71k8p0I

Comment: Works for me. Do you set anything else? Did you try a new WebBrowser? Maybe it is up to Windows 8, I'm on Win 7.

Comment: @Andy I'm Navigate another web it's not problem but I'm navigate Instagram it's problem. How to fix this ? ScreenShot http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=7o71k8p0I

Comment: Does it work when you open Instagram in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Andy Yes, It's work when i'm open in IE. but open in Web Browser Control it's not work :(

Comment: Does this change anything? WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://Instagram.com")

Comment: @Andy I'm don't change anything.

Comment: Does other websites work?

Comment: @Andy Yes, Other website it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show up as a link in your code if not: Try putting the "http://www.instagram.com" to specify to the Program it is a URL.

Comment: try go to the Instagram sign in page. Some websites are not fully compatible with certain web browsers. Maybe try updating your components. And if that does not work try use the Microsoft web browser (AxWebrowser).

Comment: Look for an update? Try this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im3K-psTVfc I only looked for about 5 minutes so pardon me if it's a bad tutorial. Another option is to download some 3rd party plugins for visual basic.